# Is an article needed in these opening statements?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I have some opening statements like:

> From programming perspective, ...

And,

> From application development perspective, ...

Not sure whether I should add definitive article for them to become:

> From a programming perspective, ...

And,

> From an application development perspective, ...

Which ones are correct?

Comment: *Perspective* is a countable noun in this sense, so a determiner has to precede it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you are putting them; a countable noun generally needs a determiner<sup>1</sup>, whether it's an article or something else. So you can use *a* (or *an* if appropriate), or *this*, or *such a*. If you're asserting that there's is precisely one *programming perspective*, it could even be *the*. The indefinite article *a* is probably safest to be sure that you're using it appropriately.

---

<sup>1</sup>: There are exceptions, but none of them apply here.